# Cocoa - specify content type in mailto URLs to include HTML

Tags: cocoa

I want to open the user's Mail client on clicking a button and populate the message body with some HTML content.

While my code successfully does that (using mailto: URL scheme), the HTML content shows up as is (i.e. the HTML is not formatted).

Is there a way I can specify that my message contains HTML when opening the Mail app? Or can I format my data like we do when typing an email in a mail client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered that a couple days ago here: [How can I send a HTML email from Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136513/how-can-i-send-a-html-email-from-cocoa/1958737#1958737)

Answer (score 1):

while specific extensions might be available on certain mailto handlers, the relevent text from [RFC 2368 - The mailto URL scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) is

> The "body" hname should contain the content for the first text/plain body part of the message.

---

The hname here refers to the 'body' in the 'body=some text' part of the mailto url. You basically get to provide a full set of email headers (name=value pairs) in the mailto url - separated by `&`'s - 'body' is defined specifically in the rfc to indicate the following text (up until the next separating '&') is the text/plain part of the message. Because there is no schema to add multiparts to an email message, you cannot express the multipart required to add the text/html part.

The only way to add a text/html part to the message would require you to be using a mailto handler that either supported an extended uri syntax, or had some way to allow you to continue programmatically adding content to the email.

Comment: Read through the specs but couldn't really make out what you're referring to here by hname.

Comment: Did you try ⌘F? “‘hname’ and ‘hvalue’ are encodings of an RFC 822 header name and value, respectively.”

Comment: Yes I did. And from what I could understand this would only work for to, cc, bcc, subject and body.

Comment: Correct. Read the last paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this, but just to give some input. [RFC2368](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html) Shows how to format mailto links, specifically how to include headers. One example of a header is "Content-type", which you would want to set to text/html in this case. So something like

```
mailto:?Content-type=text/html
```

might just work.