# Sending an E-Mail with attachments in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, text, email, attachment

I have an NSTextView with text & images in it, which is supposed to send both in an e-mail.I know that the message.framework is deprecated,so I came up with the idea to send it via NSTask, since mail is integrated.I came up with the code below, however in the log I get this:

> *** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert
>   nil value (key:
>   _NSTaskInputFileHandle)

This is the code I am using:

```
NSError *error;
    if([textView writeRTFDToFile:@"/Library/Application Support/log.rtfd" atomically:NO])
    {
        NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-s", [subject stringValue], [sendto stringValue], nil];

        NSTask *task = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
        [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/mailx"];
        [task setArguments:args];
        [task setStandardInput:[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"/Library/Application Support/log.rtfd"]];
        [task launch];
        [task waitUntilExit];
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check my answer in: [How can I send a HTML email from Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136513/how-can-i-send-a-html-email-from-cocoa/1958737#1958737)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the Scripting Bridge. See Apple's [SBSendEmail](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SBSendEmail/) example.