# Send mail from cocoa application with attachment

Tags: cocoa

How can I make a new message with attachment from my Cocoa application using Mail client? Can I do it in Lion if my application use sandbox?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313006/sending-an-e-mail-with-attachments-in-cocoa), except maybe the sandbox aspect.