# How to create a mail on Mail.app (Mac) with an image resource in the middle of the mail

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, email

I'd like to create a mail (on a Mac with Mac OS X 10.5 and up) that has some text, then an image, then some more text, maybe another image, and maybe some more text...

I understand that with the Scripting Bridge, I can add attachments to eMails, but they're always at the end of the Mail.

Any idea how to get started here? Maybe use an HTML mail? If so, are there tutorials out there?

Thank you very much and kindest regards,

Matthias

Comment: You might be better off asking at superuser.com

Comment: @Abizem: That was also my initial reaction, but I feel this post is programming related. The OP is asking about the scripting bridge, which indicates he's looking to programmatically compose a message in Mail.app from Objective-C.. different story than what a super user might do.

Comment: Check my answer in: [How can I send a HTML email from Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136513/how-can-i-send-a-html-email-from-cocoa/1958737#1958737)

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea how you can do it with Mail.app.

You can do it using [c-client](http://blog.loudhush.ro/2009/12/sending-html-email-from-cocoa.html), a plain C API.