# String formatting in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I am trying to send some text in an email from my cocoa app (by using Mail.app). Initially I tried using HTML to send properly formatted text. But the mailto: URL does not support html tags (even after setting headers)

So I decided to use formatted string (left-aligning of string) This is what I have in my mailto: link's body argument

```
NSMutableString *emailBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"|%-35s", [@"Name" UTF8String]];
[emailBody appendFormat:@"|%-18s", [@"Number" UTF8String]];
[emailBody appendString:@"|Notes\n"];

[emailBody appendString:@"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"];

for(int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++){
    NSDictionary *props = [items objectAtIndex:i];

    NSMutableString *emailData = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"|%-35s", [[props valueForKey:@"name"] UTF8String]];

    [emailData appendFormat:@"|$ %-16s", [[props valueForKey:@"number"] UTF8String]];
    [emailData appendString:[props valueForKey:@"notes"]];

    [emailBody appendString:@"\n"];
    [emailBody appendString:emailData];
}
```

This does give me padded text but they all don't necessarily take up the same space (for instance if there is an O in the text, it takes up more space than others and ruins the formatting)

Is there another sure-shot way to format text using just NSString?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what content you send via a `mailto:` URL, its formatting will be determined by the user's settings in Mail. The default setting uses a proportional font and aligning text with spaces when a proportional font is being used is doomed to failure. You can't force Mail to use a monospace font via a `mailto:` URL. You can only send a plain string to Mail this way.

In general, `mailto:` links should be used for creating only very basic email content.

If you want to control the formatting of the email, you should create an HTML email as outlined in [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136513/how-can-i-send-a-html-email-from-cocoa/1958737#1958737).

Comment: Thanks I was originally using catlan's github code. But that only worked on SL and above. the one in the answer works on both.